# Efficient selection of data from SQL point cloud x,y,z

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an SQL table in Postgres with columns `x`, `y`, `z`. I have *indexes* on `x` and `y`. Table is around **3 Gb** in size.

To select an area of data I run a query of the form:

```
SELECT x, y, z 
  FROM table 
 WHERE (x BETWEEN lowX and highX) 
   AND (y BETWEEN lowY and highY)
```

Is this the *most efficient way* to code the select statement? Thanks for your advice.

Comment: What datatypes are the columns

Comment: They're all float. I used x,y,z but they're actually grid easting, northing and depth in metres with cm accuracy.

Comment: which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Which of them has more different values? x or y?

Comment: Could be either. It's a grid with values roughtly every 4cm in both planes. The exact way the data comes in depends on how the data was gathered, the heading the sensor was driven in.

Comment: I'm using Postgres but will have to add Oracle support soon.

Answer (score 1):

SQL is a *declarative* language - you use SQL to define what data you want; it's up to the database engine to decide the *most efficient* way to fetch the data.

That said, if you have only individual indices on `x` and `y`, then only one will be used (the table rows matching the `x` index will be scanned to determine if they meet the `y` and `z` criteria).  A *compound index* on `x` and `y` would allow the engine to just scan the items that meet both conditions:

```
CREATE INDEX table_xy_idx ON table (x, y);
```

Note that this renders your index on `x` obsolete, since the compound index can be used to find matching `x` values for a given query.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using postgresql I recommend using [geometry](https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html) data type and [spatial index](http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/indexing.html). The efficiency is dependent on the selectivity of your queries, however, it is worth to try.